# Ayuda Structura y Vector en C, Simple programa de Alumnos y Notas

Tags: c, array, estructuras-de-datos

¿Cómo hacer un vector? ¿De qué forma hacer para no ir poniendo `nota1;nota2;nota3;etc`? Hice 2 códigos, pero no me funcionan. ¿Cómo hacer con el tema del promedio?

1) Ingresar los datos de los alumnos de un establecimiento consistentes en `NOMBRE` (string 30 caracteres), `SEXO` (char), y `NOTAS` de `10` materias codificadas de `0` a `9` (int). El ingreso terminará cuando se ingrese 
el nombre `FIN`.

2) Indicar la cantidad de alumnos que hay en el establecimiento cuyo promedio sea mayor o igual que `4` y menor que `7`.

Transcripción de la fotocopia que pidieron hacer:

> 1. Ingresar los datos de los alumnos de un establecimiento consistentes
>      en NOMBRE (string de 30 caracteres), SEXO (char) y NOTAS de 10
>      materias codificadas de 0 a 9 (int). El ingreso terminará cuando se
>      ingrese el nombre "FIN". Se sabe que el establecimiento no tiene más
>      de 10000 alumnos.
> 2. Imprimir la lista de las 10 mejores alumnas.
> 3. Indicar cuántos alumnos hay en el establecimiento cuyo promedio sea
>      mayor o igual que 4 y menor que siete.
> 4. Permitir el ingreso de un nombre y mostrar la totalidad de sus
>      datos, o bien, si no pertenece al establecimiento.

Código 1:

```
#include stdio.h
#include stdlib.h
#include ncurses.h
#include string.h

struct promedio{
    int nota1;
    int nota2;
    int nota3;
    int nota4;
    int nota5;
    int nota6;
    int nota7;
    int nota8;
    int nota9;
    int nota10;
};

struct alumno{
    char nombre[20];
    char sexo[20];
    int edad;
    struct promedio prom;
}alumnos[100];

int main(){
    int n,i,pmay;
    int promedio[100], mayor = 0;
    printf("Digite el total de alumnos: ");
    scanf("%i",&n);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){

        printf("%i. Digite su nombre: ",i+1);
        scanf("%s",alumnos[i].nombre);
        printf("%i. Digite su sexo: ",i+1);
        scanf("%s",alumnos[i].sexo);
        printf("%i. Digite sus notas: ",i+1);
        scanf("%i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i",&alumnos[i].prom.nota1,
        &alumnos[i].prom.nota2,&alumnos[i].prom.nota3,&alumnos[i].prom.nota4,
      &alumnos[i].prom.nota5,&alumnos[i].prom.nota6,&alumnos[i].prom.nota7,&alumnos[i].prom.nota8,
      &alumnos[i].prom.nota9,&alumnos[i].prom.nota10);
        printf("\n");

        promedio[i] = (alumnos[i].prom.nota1+alumnos[i].prom.nota2+alumnos[i].prom.nota3+alumnos[i].prom.nota4+alumnos[i].prom.nota5+
        alumnos[i].prom.nota6+alumnos[i].prom.nota7+alumnos[i].prom.nota8+alumnos[i].prom.nota9+alumnos[i].prom.nota10)/3;

        if(promedio[i] > mayor){
            mayor = promedio[i];
            pmay = i;
        }
    }

    printf("\n- El Alumno con Mayor Promedio-\n");
    printf("\nNombre: %s",alumnos[pmay].nombre);
    printf("\nSexo: %s",alumnos[pmay].sexo);
    printf("\nPromedio: %i\n",promedio[pmay]);


    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Código 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 100

struct {
    char nombre[20];
    char sexo;
    int notas[10];
} alumno[MAX];

int main() {
    int j,i=0,suma,a,b,c;
    float promedio=0.0;

    while (1) {
        printf("Nombre del alumno (para terminar teclee FIN): ");
        scanf("%s",alumno[i].nombre);
        getchar();

        if (strcmp(alumno[i].nombre,"FIN") == 0)
            break;
        else {
            printf("Sexo: M o F: ");
            scanf("%c",&alumno[i].sexo);
            for (j=0; j<10; j++) {
                printf("Ingrese nota # %d: ",j+1);
                scanf("%d",&alumno[i].notas[j]);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
        i += 1;
    }

    for (a=0; a<i; a++) {
        suma = 0;
        for (b=0; b<10; b++)
            suma = suma+alumno[a].notas[b];

        promedio = suma/3;
        if (promedio >= 4 && promedio < 7)
            c += 1;
    }
    printf("Total de alumnos con promedio >= 4 y promedio < 7 = ");
    printf("%d",c);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

El problema que tiene la primera propuesta es que es complicado hacer el cálculo de promedios porque no puedes meter un bucle. La mejor opción sería hacer uso de la segunda, que además tiene menos código:

```
#define MAX_NOTAS 10

struct alumno
{
    char nombre[20];
    char sexo;
    int notas[MAX_NOTAS];
};
```

Por otro lado, en el enunciado te están diciendo lo siguiente:

> Ingresar los datos de los alumnos de un establecimiento consistentes en NOMBRE (string de 30 caracteres), SEXO (char) y NOTAS de 10 materias codificadas de 0 a 9 (int). El ingreso terminará cuando se ingrese el nombre "FIN". **Se sabe que el establecimiento no tiene más de 10000 alumnos**.

En la parte destacada ya te están dando un límite de alumnos. Lo primero que tienes que hacer es reservar espacio suficiente para almacenar ese número de elementos. Yo personalmente evitaría hacer uso de variables globales ya que a la larga te van a dar más problemas que alegrías. Así mismo evitaría introducir literales entre el código:

```
#define MAX_ALUMNOS 10000

int main()
{
  struct alumno alumnos[MAX_ALUMNOS];
}
```

El bucle para introducir alumnos debe terminar cuando se introduzca la palabra `"FIN"`, aunque ya que tenemos un tope de alumnos no estaría de más verificar que no excedemos dicho límite aunque sea por error:

```
int num_alumnos;
for( num_alumnos=0; num_alumnos<MAX_ALUMNOS; num_alumnos++ )
{
  printf("Nombre del alumno (para terminar teclee FIN): ");
  scanf("%s",alumnos[num_alumnos].nombre);
  if( strcmp(alumnos[num_alumnos].nombre,"FIN") == 0 )
    break;
  // else ....
  // nota que como el if tiene un break no es necesario el else
}
```

Cuando aprendes a programar te das cuenta de que tienes que tratar al usuario como si fuese un completo inutil y pudiese confundirse siempre... imagina que quien va a usar el programa es un mono que aporrea el teclado... tienes que comprobar todo lo que se introduce para saber si es válido:

```
do
{
  char sexo;
  printf("Sexo: M o F: ");
  scanf("%c",&sexo);
  alumnos[num_alumnos].sexo = toupper(sexo);
} while( alumnos[num_alumnos].sexo != 'M' && alumnos[num_alumnos].sexo !='F');
```

Y finalmente, para introducir las notas, podemos hacer uso de la constante que hemos declarado al principio (la gracia de usar constantes es que si queremos hacer pruebas rápidas únicamente hay que cambiar valores en un sitio);

```
for (int j=0; j<MAX_NOTAS; j++)
{
  printf("Ingrese nota # %d: ",j+1);
  scanf("%d",&alumnos[num_alumnos].notas[j]);
}
```

Ahora revisamos el promedio:

```
for (int i=0; i<; a++) {
  suma = 0;
  for (b=0; b<10; b++)
    suma = suma+alumnos[a].notas[b];

  int promedio = suma/3; // <<--- AQUI!!!
  if (promedio >= 4 && promedio < 7)
    c += 1;
}
```

¿Por qué divides la suma entre 3? ¿No hemos quedado en que son 10 notas? Este es uno de los problemas asociados al uso de literales en el código:

```
int resultado = 0;
for (int i=0; i<num_alumnos; i++) {
  int suma = 0;
  for (int j=0; j<MAX_NOTAS; j++)
    suma += alumnos[i].notas[j];

  promedio = suma/MAX_NOTAS;

  // Esto ...
  if (promedio >= 4 && promedio < 7)
    resultado++;
  // ... es equivalente a ...
  resultado += (promedio >= 4 && promedio < 7);
}
```

Y con estos cambios el programa debería funcionarte.

Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta me ha servido de mucho, pero el promedio me sigue dando mal.

Comment: Si el promedio lo quieres con decimales tendrás que calcular el resultado en un float

Comment: O eso o te has equivocado al llevar los cambios a tu programa

Comment: @GabrielForzza Prueba a declarar promedio dentro del bucle... No vaya a ser que estés sumando promedios sin darte cuenta

Answer (score 0):

La idea de este foro es plantear dudas puntuales sobre problemas de programación específicos. Las preguntas pidiendo respuestas sobre como resolver un ejercicio entero generalmente no son bien recibidas, igualmente te tiro algunas ayudas para que lo puedas resolver.

La estructura que deberías usar es la siguiente:

```
Struct alumno {
    char nombre[30];
    char sexo;
    int notas[10];
    float promedio;
};
```

Para el sexo no es necesario usar un vector, ya que la consiga te pide un char. Asumo que los hombres llevarán una M en ese campo y las mujeres una F.
Para las notas no es necesario crear una estructura como venias haciendo, lo que hice fue poner un vector adentro de las estructura que contendrá las 10 notas de cada alumno.
También agregué una variable del tipo float donde se guardará el promedio de las 10 notas.

Lo primero que tenes que hacer es ocuparte de la carga de los alumnos, como no sabes que cantidad de alumnos se van a ingresar forzosamente tendrás que usar memoria dinámica.

Para esto, lo primero que tenes que hacer es declarar una variable del tipo alumno:

```
struct alumno primer_dato;
```

Luego le pedis al usuario que ingrese el nombre del alumno. Si el nombre es distinto de FIN (condición de finalización según la consigna), almacenas el nombre en la variable creada y le pedis al usuario que ingrese el sexo y las 10 notas (ahí calculas el promedio) e insertas todos los datos en la misma estructura. En ese momento tendrás toda la estructura cargada y deberás pedir memoria usando la función malloc, para luego agregar el nodo a una lista que deberás crear. Este proceso se repetirá siempre hasta que el nombre ingresado sea FIN.

Cuando tú lista este completamente cargada con todos los alumnos, podes seguir con los puntos 2, 3 y 4 de tu consigna.

Answer (score 0):

> ¿Cómo hacer un vector? ¿De qué forma hacer para no ir poniendo `nota1;nota2;nota3;etc`?

Deduzco (puede que erróneamente) que quieres saber cómo hacer un vector en memoria dinámica, ya que en otras partes de tu código veo que ya sabes hacer vectores en memoria estática.

Para crear un vector en memoria dinámica deberás usar la función [`malloc`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc), la cuál se encarga de alojar memoria (`m`emory `alloc`ation).

La función `malloc` pertenece a la cabecera `<stdlib.h>`:

```
void* malloc( size_t recuento_de_bytes );
```

Aloja `recuento_de_bytes` bytes de memoria no inicializada (esto es: que contendrá datos con valores indeterminados). Si consigue alojar la memoria solicitada se devolverá un puntero al inicio del bloque de memoria solicitada.

Así que si quieres 10 valores enteros para tu promedio deberías hacer lo siguiente:

```
// Aloja memoria para 10 int
int *promedio = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
```

La instrucción `sizeof(int)` devuelve el tamaño del tipo `int`, que generalmente es de 4 bytes (en la mayoría de sistemas de 32 bits) así que la cantidad de bytes necesarios para alojar 10 enteros sería 40 bytes (`10 * sizeof(int)`).

Podrás acceder a cada uno de los 10 enteros usando los corchetes (`[` y `]`) contando que el primer entero será el índice 0 y el último el índice 9:

```
/* Ponemos todos los datos a 0 porque
malloc devuelve memoria no inicializada. */
for (int indice = 0; indice < 10; ++indice)
    promedio[indice] = 0;
```

No hay que olvidar que la memoria solicitada por `malloc` no es liberada a no ser que así se indique. Para liberar la memoria hay que usar la función [`free`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free):

```
void free( void* puntero_a_memoria_dinamica );
```

También pertenece a la cabecera `<stdlib.h>` y liberará la memoria solicitada dinámicamente, para ello hay que pasarle el puntero apuntando al inicio del bloque de la memoria que se solicitó dinámicamente.

> Ingresar los datos de los alumnos de un establecimiento consistentes en `NOMBRE` (string 30 caracteres), `SEXO` (char), y `NOTAS` de `10` materias codificadas de `0` a `9` (int). El ingreso terminará cuando se ingrese 
>   el nombre `FIN`.

Por lo que puedo ver esto lo tienes casi solucionado, pero no compruebas que te ingresen el nombre `FIN` para dejar de pedir datos. Para comparar el texto ingresado contra un texto determinado deberás usar `strcmp` o mejor `strncmp`, ambas pertenecen a la cabecera `<string.h>`.

`strcmp` es una función de comparación de cadenas de caracteres, recibe un puntero al primer caracter a comparar de la primera cadena y un puntero al primer caracter a comparar de la segunda cadena. El resultado es un número entero:

```
int strcmp( const char *cadena_izquierda, const char *cadena_derecha );
```

El resultado puede obtiener los valores `-1`, `0` o `1` dependiendo del resultado de la comparación: `cadena_izquierda` menor a `cadena_derecha`, `cadena_izquierda` y `cadena_derecha` iguales o `cadena_izquierda` mayor a `cadena_derecha` respectivamente.

`strncmp` es la versión *segura* de `strcmp` que añade un parámetro con el número máximo de caracteres a comparar:

```
int strncmp( const char *cadena_izquierda, const char *cadena_derecha, size_t maximo );
```

Sabiendo que `NOMBRE` será siempre una cadena de 30 caracteres podrías usar esta función.

> Indicar la cantidad de alumnos que hay en el establecimiento cuyo promedio sea mayor o igual que `4` y menor que `7`.

Una vez tienes todas las notas en tu vector, sólo deberás recorrerlas y contar la cantidad de elementos que cumplan con la condición:

```
int promedio_entre_4_y_7 = 0;

for (int indice = 0; indice < cantidad_de_alumnos; ++indice)
    if ((promedio[indice] >= 4) && (promedio[indice] < 7))
        ++promedio_entre_4_y_7;
```

En la condición he puesto paréntesis entre cada una de las comparaciones pero no es necesario por la [precedencia de operadores](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) ya que `>=` y `<` tienen una precedencia mayor que `&&`.

Comment: Gracias por responder, todavia no manejo punteros y memoria dinamica, pero me aclaraste bastante.Se agradece.Salu2!